# How to launch activity while screen is Locked screen in Android 10

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-10.0

I have to launch an activity when the device is locked, I used the below code to launch the activity from service. it works fine below the android 10 device.

```
val callIntent = Intent(this, CallActivity::class.java)
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
callIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALL_TYPE, callType)
callIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALL_DIRECTION, callDirection)
startActivity(callIntent)
```

This code not working in Android 10, any other way to launch the activity in Android 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a notification instead, with [fullScreenIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%2520boolean)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need permission to background services